# WPF Deploying Updates to Non MS Store App

Tags: wpf, powershell, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, app.xaml

I created a Windows (WPF) App not intended for Store release.  Owner did not want a proprietary, internal use only app, openly available on the store. The app is currently installed on Windows 10 Pro tablets.  The app was programmed using Visual Studio 2013.  Since the conception of this project, I have had trouble finding resources I can reference to take the app to the next stage.  Hoping someone out there can help me define what I am looking for so I can more easily find a resource to resolve my issue.

My app is deployed and functioning well in the field.  The owner has now requested a modification to the app.  The install of the app was relatively simple. Visual Studio allowed for either Store publication (upload) or Create an App package.  I have used Create an App package for the first time install. The package comes with a powerscript which I manually run from a stick and the app installs.  Updates worked the same.  App is deploying to more remote computers than originally thought making manual updates harder.

I would now like to see if I can add a button to the app that downloads the update files and performs the powerscript to update the app.  Or, can I put the files on a server with a web page interface that could initiate the download and process of the update similar to what MS Store does.  Maybe the app can call the webpage from a button and close the app so the process can update the app.

I am finding some WPF references about using ClickOnce, xCopy and others but the instructions reference using options like Publish which is not an available option in Visual Studio for this Project.  I've seen this in Web Apps and VB apps but not this one.  Thus the problem finding what applies to my situation.

Suggestions on keywords I can use for searching or links to possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have a WPF app? I don't think 'Create an App Package' is an option for WPF projects, it sounds to me like you have created some kind fo Universal Windows App or something

Comment: According to properties the Target Platform is Windows 8.1. Output Type is Windows Store App. Pages in App are XAML with XAML.vb

Comment: Does those settings make it a Universal Windows App?

Comment: Yes, it is a Windows Store App which cannot be deployed using ClickOnce.

I'm afraid I don't know so much about Windows Store Apps myself

Comment: Thank you for at least reviewing and helping clarify terms. Appreciate it.